# split a 2 digit variable number to two input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible to split a two digit variable into two input fields, for example:

lets say i have a variable `var age = 23;` and i want to split that to `<input class="age" id = "age1" />` and `<input class="age" id = "age2" />` so that age1's value is 2 and age2's value is 3.

Any Help Greatly appreciated...

this is how i am getting the value of age:

```
$.each(age_input_groups , function(i){
                var id = 'age-group-'+g_counter;
                var agevalues = $.map($('#'+id + ' input') , function(e,i){
                    return $(e).val(age);
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do this:

```
var age = 23;
document.getElementById('age1').value = Math.floor(age / 10);
document.getElementById('age2').value = age % 10;
```

And an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wQaGN/1/).

---

For your case you can use the following JavaScript:

```
var age = 23,
    g_counter = 1;

$('.group').each(function(i){
  var id = 'input-group'+g_counter,
      selector = '#'+id + ' input',
      elem = $(selector);
  g_counter += 1;
  elem.first().val(Math.floor(age / 10));
  elem.last().val(age % 10);
});
```

With:

```
<div id="input-group1" class="group">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div id="input-group2" class="group">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

One more [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wQaGN/3/). If you have a list of ages you can use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wQaGN/4/).

And last example with the [final solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/hkJ6K/4/)

Comment: sorry it wouldn't allow me to edit my question for a while, but how would i do that using the method of getting age in the question

Comment: Wow thanks, helps alot already.. cant seem to get it working with my code, so here's jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/hkJ6K/2/ i tryd to remove all unnecessary code. but theres the base.. the problem is that this: $.each(age_input_groups , function(i){
                var id = 'age-group-'+g_counter;
                var agevalues = $.map($('#'+id + ' input') , function(e,i){
                    return $(e).val(age);
                });
            }); - this i cant change to much cause it returns the value etc.. so it needs to have the same end result.. if you understand

Comment: .. oh and here an example of an ID that you fill in: 85 0929 5266086

Comment: look at what the JSON returns in console on submit: http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/hkJ6K/5/

Comment: Hey, if you get time, could you possibly take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597955/jquery-form-plugin-submitting-fields-not-forms ... please

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**substring()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) and convert the number to string.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/5swa3/)**

```
var age = '23';
age1 = age.toString();
docucment.getElementById('age1').value = age1.substring(0,1);
docucment.getElementById('age2').value = age1.substring(1,2);
```

Comment: First you need to convert `age` to a string.

Comment: sorry it wouldn't allow me to edit my question for a while, but how would i do that using the method of getting age in the question

Answer (score 2):

A string can be accessed as an array to get individual characters. Therefore you can use this:

```
var foo = 23;
$('#age1').val(foo.toString()[0]);
$('#age2').val(foo.toString()[1]);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/7JWk7/)

Comment: sorry it wouldn't allow me to edit my question for a while, but how would i do that using the method of getting age in the question

Comment: Can you also post your HTML in your OP.